# Execute java file from Chrome link

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a setting in Chrome where I can launch a java file directly by clicking a hyperlink?

Right now, when I click the link, the file downloads. I then have to select run. Is there a way to simply execute the file without the intermediate step?

I'm ending up with hundreds of copies of downloaded files. I can't just use a prior download because the file version may change while the name remains constant.

Comment: What do you mean by a java file? file.java? Or something else?

Comment: They currently download .jnlp files.  I want to just open the file when clicking the hyperlink rather than having to say "yes I want to keep the file" then click again to open the file.

Comment: It's a bug.  [Issue 518170:  jnlp files are now showing with " Always Open Files of This Type" grayed out](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=518170) Aug 8, 2015.

Comment: @JeffreyKramer Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: @Siddhartha nope